# How to Create an MSI Installer in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-installer

I've got a C# project in Visual Studio code, and I've installed the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension. But, when I right-click on the project and click Build (from the Release), the .MSI file is not created. I'm not sure why. I think it might have something to do with the configuration manager saying that MSI Setup  Incompatible.  The strange thing is, I was able to get the MSI file created on a different computer, but when I started doing development on this one, it won't get created.

Do you have any ideas how I can get the MSI file created? Thanks in advance! [image]

Comment: I *think* you have to select a specific CPU/platform for your Setup projects. So, you'll need to create separate configs for each platform to distribute (x86, x64, etc.)

Comment: That was part of my problem - I needed to choose x86 for the platform. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to create the MSI file. Here's what I did:

1. Downloaded a fresh copy of the project from Gitlab.
2. Opened the Configuration Manager and checkmarked the Build box in the Setup entry. [image]
3. Selected the x86 platform from the drop-down and Release from the build-type drop-down.
4. Right-clicked on the Setup folder and chose Rebuild Solution (before I was right-clicking on the Project and choosing Rebuild solution).[image]